# squeeze! not working

Tags: ruby, string

I have a text file that I am opening and creating objects from. 
It looks like this:

```
/home/music/Accident Murderer.mp3|4:37|    Nas       |    Accident Murderer
/home/music/Bitch Bad.mp3        |4:49| Lupe   Fiasco|    Bitch Bad
/home/music/ITAL.mp3             |4:24| Lupe   Fiasco|    ITAL(Roses)
/home/music/The Coolest.mp3      |5:13| Lupe   Fiasco|    The Coolest
```

I am then using the folloing code to create song objects:

```
songs = SongList.new
songFile = File.open('./songs.txt')
songFile.each do |line|
  file, length, name, title = line.chomp.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
  name.squeeze!(" ")
  mins, secs = length.scan(/\d+/)
  songs.append Karaoke::Song.new(title, name, mins.to_i*60+secs.to_i)
end
```

However I am getting the following error message:

```
songlist.rb:40:in `block in <class:SongList>': undefined method `squeeze!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError).
```

Can somebody please help. I do not understand why 'squeeze!' is an undefined method. It's a String class method right?

Comment: it seems like your `name` variable is nil (null), First check if you are getting the correct value/ not nil for the variable `name`

Comment: Why use that regex when you probably just want a split on `"|"`?

Comment: i'm pretty sure i am getting the correct value for name b/c when i take off the 'name.squeeze!' line and the 'mins, secs = length.scan' line everything seems to work fine

Comment: @user2216571 That's unlikely; name is `nil` at *some* point, because you're calling `squeeze!` on a `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have a blank line you are processing? Perhaps at the end of the file? That would split into `["",nil,nil,nil]`, so `name` would be `nil` and that cause the error you are seeing . . .

The fix for that would look like this:

```
songs = SongList.new
songFile = File.open('./songs.txt')
songFile.each do |line|
  next if line.chomp.empty?
  file, length, name, title = line.chomp.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
  raise "Got less than four columns, line '#{line.chomp}'" if title == nil 
  name.squeeze!(" ")
  mins, secs = length.scan(/\d+/)
  songs.append Karaoke::Song.new(title, name, mins.to_i*60+secs.to_i)
end
```

The `next` should skip any simple empty line, but you could alter it to skip anything you'd like to treat as "ok in the input file, but does not contain data for my script".

I also added a simple validation which will raise an error if a line looks ok initially, but is unexpectedly missing the last column. I'd generally recommend this approach, at least some stage during processing of data that comes from outside the code, you should check it really is what you expect or need.

What actually counts as ok to skip, and what is an error in the input file is up to you. This modification should at the very least give you some more clues on what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks dude that fix makes a lot of sense. However I am getting a Runtime error and i do not really know what it consists of as i am new to ruby.

Comment: the code you provided does not help at all and I did try checking for blank lines but I haven't had any luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user2216571 Try just splitting on `|` instead and see what the resulting array looks like.  I feel like you don't need the regex you have now.